# Consecutive Prime relations

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers

Let $p$ and $q$ denote two consecutive prime numbers. Does any pair $p,q$ satisfy $q >2 p + 2$? Can it be proved?

Comment: no, Bertrand's Postulate. It was proved....

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to Bertrand's postulate, it says that what you asked never happens.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate

Answer (score 0):

No. Take $p=2$ and $q=3$. Then $q\leqslant2p+2$.